# pthread mutex not unlocking on wait

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, mutex

I'm using c posix threads, and i've encountered a problem I don't quite understand and would like some fresh eyes to see what the problem could be.

In summary, I'm creating 3 threads which check some program state, signal that they are ready, and then wait for further signals. Meanwhile the thread that created these threads is waiting (pthread_cond_wait_) for each thread to signal that it has been setup. However it seems that the mutex is never unlocked once a wait has been signaled, causing the program the halt entirely.

This is the code for the main thread:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
    if (scenario->flags.sinkThreadSetup == 0) {
        pthread_create(&sinkT, NULL, sinkProblemHandler, (void *)scenario);
        pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->sinkSetupCondition, &scenario->mutex);
    }
    if (scenario->flags.freeThreadSetup == 0) {
        pthread_create(&freeT, NULL, freeWheelProblemHandler, (void *)scenario);
        pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->freeSetupCondition, &scenario->mutex);
    }
    if (scenario->flags.blockThreadSetup == 0) {
        pthread_create(&blockT, NULL, blockProblemHandler, (void *)scenario);
        pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->blockSetupCondition, &scenario->mutex);
    }
    scenario->state = VECTORING;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);

    // Start wheel threads
    pthread_t wheelThreads[NUM_WHEELS];
    scenario_wheel_t threadDataArr[NUM_WHEELS];
    for (int i =0; i < NUM_WHEELS; i++) {
        threadDataArr[i].scenario = scenario;
        threadDataArr[i].wheel = &scenario->wheels[i];
        pthread_create(&wheelThreads[i], NULL, wheel_start, (void *)&threadDataArr[i]);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->scenarioComplete_condition, &scenario->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
```

Here is the code for the problem handler threads:

```
void *sinkProblemHandler(void *args) {
    scenario_t *scenario = (scenario_t *) args;
    while(scenario->flags.terminate != 1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
        if (scenario->state == SETUP && scenario->flags.sinkThreadSetup == 0) {
            scenario->flags.sinkThreadSetup = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&scenario->sinkSetupCondition);
        }
        if (scenario->state != SINKING) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->conditions.sinking_condition, &scenario->mutex);
            if (scenario->flags.terminate == 1) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
            printf("SINKHandler: I'M HELPING!");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *blockProblemHandler(void *args) {
    scenario_t *scenario = (scenario_t *) args;
    while(scenario->flags.terminate != 1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
        if (scenario->state == SETUP && scenario->flags.blockThreadSetup == 0) {
            scenario->flags.blockThreadSetup = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&scenario->blockSetupCondition);
        }
        if (scenario->state != BLOCKED) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->conditions.blocked_condition, &scenario->mutex);
            if (scenario->flags.terminate == 1) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
            printf("BlockHandler: I'M HELPING!");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *freeWheelProblemHandler(void * args) {
    scenario_t *scenario = (scenario_t *) args;
    while(scenario->flags.terminate != 1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
        if (scenario->state == SETUP && scenario->flags.freeThreadSetup == 0) {
            scenario->flags.freeThreadSetup = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&scenario->freeSetupCondition);
        }
        if (scenario->state != BLOCKED) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&scenario->conditions.freeWheeling_condition, &scenario->mutex);
            if (scenario->flags.terminate == 1) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
            printf("FreeHandler: I'M HELPING!");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

We can see here that the problem handler threads signal their respective setup condition, and then wait for a different condition (pthread_cond_wait),which should unlock the mutex.

My initial thought was that the problem handler threads were signaling before the main thread has started waiting, thus creating a deadlock. However after attaching to the program, this is not the case, as the program does:
 1. Starts a problem thread
 2. waits for the problem setup condition (unlocking mutex)
 3. problem handler thread lock mutex.
 3. problem handler thread then signals setup complete
 4. problem handler thread then waits (supposedly unlocking mutex)
 5. Program halts completely.  (like the mutex has not been unlocked).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what I find strange is `pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);` in your main program. It may create the deadlock with the threads which do the same thing.

Comment: At the end of the code for the main thread, you have all the other threads suspended waiting on condition variables... then the main thread locks the mutex and waits on a condition as well, which nobody will signal because they're all waiting on conditions of their own.  (or so it appears... I didn't look carefully enough to be sure I haven't missed something)

Comment: What's in `wheel_start()`?

Comment: Please include your complete program that interested people can run easily for testing and debugging.  See the guidelines here [mcve]

Comment: Make sure your printing operations include a newline at the end.  Otherwise, you're not guaranteed to see the output in a timely manner.  That's mostly a minor issue, but it definitely affects debuggability.   How have you attempted to debug the code?  Are you running it in a debugger, or using print statements?  (I tend to favour print statements, but I'm old-fahsioned and/or low-tech and/or too lazy to learn how to debug multi-threaded programs in a debugger.)

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem,  post code that is short, cleanly compiles, and still exhibits the problem. The posted code does not compile (no main(), no included headers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your worker threads roughly all have the form of

```
while(var) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&scenario->mutex);
  // ...
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&scenario->mutex);
}
```

that is mutex is locked immediately after it is unlocked. The main thread has a little chance to continue execution, as it cannot reacquire the mutex.

This is from `man pthread_cond_signal`:

> The thread(s) that are unblocked shall contend for the mutex according to the scheduling policy (if applicable), and as if each had called pthread_mutex_lock().

So, at a bare minimum you can try `pthread_yield()` before reacquiring the mutex in the worker threads; and even better reduce the usage of mutex and / or introduce different mutexes to let different sections run in parallel.

Comment: If the threads are spending most of their time waiting on condition variables, they may not really have the mutex locked that much... though if the intent is that the other threads do their work during the condition waits, it'd make more sense to lock before the loop and unlock after.

Comment: To allow the waiting thread to continue, the thread that called pthread_cond_signal() also needs to release the mutex.